# "Error: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." Watson visual recognition

Tags: node.js, visual-recognition, watson

Im getting the error above while trying to create a new classification using the IBM watson visual recognition system.

```
        var VisualRecognitionV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/visualrecognition/v3');

        var visual_recognition = new VisualRecognitionV3({
           api_key: <api-key>,
           version_date: '2016-05-19'
        });
```

This is how I am fetching the credentials, from the examples that the documentation provided. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I am receiving the same exact error. I wonder if it's an error on their part.

Answer (score 0):

The visual recognition coding provided by IBM Watson, was successfully build and run on Android Studio 2.3.3,
However as I install and run on an actual device, it will prone "Invalid Visual Recognition Credentials" even though "README.md" indicate "Your unique Visual Recognition Api Key has been injected into your application so no further config is needed"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="visualrecognitionApi_key">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
<string name="visualrecognitionUrl">https://gateway-
a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api</string>
```